# problem with chmod command

Tags: permissions, chmod

I don't know what is happening

```
experimentx@workmateX:/var/www$ sudo chmod 0777 -r /var/www/

chmod: cannot access `0777': No such file or directory

experimentx@workmateX:/var/www$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
sudo chmod 0777 -R /var/www/
```

**-R** instead of **-r**.

Comment: well thanks to you both ... but what the hell happened? I had been using `-r` untill now, and suddenly .. `-R`

Comment: There was no `-r` in `chmod` ever, there is only `-R` or `--recursive`.

Comment: Yeah, chmod doesn't have any `-r` option.

Comment: well, i had been doing `-r` until i updated my system yesterday .. on version 10.10

Comment: I don't know what happened in your case but chmod is one the commands that are common between all linux distributions and has nothing to the with a specific version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

Use "-R" instead of "-r".

From the chmod help:

> -R, --recursive         change files and directories recursively

Answer (score 2):

Also note that the 0 will no longer clear suid/sgid/sticky in recent versions of chmod and you'll soon have to use a symbolic mode (if that's what you're intending to do).

- [coreutils bug#8391: chmod setuid & setguid bits](http://osdir.com/ml/bug-coreutils-gnu/2011-04/msg00001.html)
- [Red Hat Bug 691466 - [RFE] Enable octal-digit mode for removal of UID/GID/sticky bits](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691466)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps going or directing the file in terminal and once you locate file by:

```
ls
```

then run the command:

```
chmod +x filename
```

from that location I'm sure it will work.